# Sending links via email

Tags: php, html-email, phpmailer

I'm trying to send a website link via email. The classic

`<a href="website.com" target="_blank">website</a>`

The problem is when I receive the email and try to open it. It doesn't want to redirect to the website. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, can someone help?

I'm not sure if this will help but I'm using PHPMailer with the msgHTML method, which seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fully qualifying the URL, I'm not sure the email client will be able to resolve a relative path.

http://website.com

Comment: To be clear, the client will **not** be able to resolve a relative path because an email message has no base URL to be relative to. All links must be absolute. You can use a `base` tag, but everything will break if the `head` tag is stripped, which some stupid webmail clients do.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<a href="http://website.com" target="_blank">website</a>`.

Your not e a protocol and its not obvious for your email client that its a link to a http or https protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="http://www.website.com" target="_blank">website</a>
```

In email content we have to provide absolute path instead of relative path